# "Permission denied" when trying to record audio after ON_BOOT_RECEIVED (Android 11)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11

I have an android app that runs a foreground service that records audio. To do this I use an `AudioRecord` object that I initialize like so:

```
this.audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampRate, rec_channel_code, _encoding, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

The app is also configured to run automatically on `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

When I run the app manually, either by pressing the icon or from Android Studio, everything works great, audio is recorded and there's no issue - So I know I'm opening the recorder correctly, and I have permissions to do it.

The problem is, when the app runs automatically after boot, it doesn't work at all. I get several error messages, the first one being:

```
permission denied: recording not allowed for uid 10388 pid 7413
```

And then there's these ones, that are probably a result of the permission error:

```
E/AudioRecord: createRecord_l(0): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

If I then stop the service and run it manually again, it works fine. It doesn't even ask for permissions, because it has them already.

I'm running Android 11, but I have no idea if this happens in previous versions.

So I guess my question is, is it even possible to record audio from a foreground service that runs automatically on boot? And if it is, how do I make it happen?

Things I've tried so far:

- Wait for about a minute before opening the mic, in case it's just some initialization error
- Run the `Activity` that activates the `ForegroundService`, instead of the service itself, when activating from the `BootReceiver` (so it can request permissions again, if needed) - This doesn't work as the ActivityManager kills my activity immediately

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, it seems that according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services), it simply isn't possible.

> To help protect user privacy, Android 11 (API level 30) introduces limitations to when a foreground service can access the device's location, camera, or microphone. When your app starts a foreground service while the app is running in the background, the foreground service has the following limitations:
>
> - Unless the user has granted the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission to your app, the foreground service cannot access location.
> - The foreground service **cannot access the microphone or camera**.

The user has to have some kind of active interaction with the app to allow the foreground service to start recording, such as displaying a notification that says "Tap here to start recording".